# Simulate "Enter" keypress after successfully making connection using Netcat on Raspberry Pi

Tags: shell-script, raspbian, netcat

I have an issue with using Netcat on Raspberry Pi terminal to output data after making a connection. The issue is that when I run this command, after it is succeeded, 5 seconds pass, and the connection is disconnected:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nc -vn -w5 192.168.0.50 54567
Connection to 192.168.0.50 54567 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

However, if I run this same command but press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before the 5 seconds are up, I get this output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nc -vn -w5 192.168.0.50 54567
Connection to 192.168.0.50 54567 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
{"header":{"version":"2.0","protocol_version":3,"message_type":"message_ack","packet_counter":1,"request_ack":false,"os_datetimestamp":2021-06-08T14:37:38.669-06:00"},"data":{"ack_packet_counter":0,"error_code":999}}
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

I want to be able to write either a shell script or a Python script that runs this command and also simulates <kbd>Enter</kbd> so that I can see the data. Once the script is done, I want it to end with the Terminal open. Is there any way to do this? I can't find a simple option online.

Comment: Probably it's enough to send a newline character to `nc`: `echo | nc …`. What do you mean by "once the script is done, I want it to end with the Terminal open"? If you run a script from a shell in a terminal (terminal emulator) then after the script finishes you are back in the shell. Or do you want to run the script from a desktop "shortcut", by double-clicking or in another non-CLI way? What way exactly? Then yes, it's reasonable to want the terminal emulator not to close. What terminal emulator? Do you want an interactive shell to pop up after the script is done? Plese [edit] and clarify.